# Ionic 4 keyboard is covering whole content

Tags: ionic-framework

When i am clicking on input keyboard covers all the content. i need to show the input top/up/above to keyboard as in whatsapp app.

```
 <div *ngSwitchCase="'home'">
      <!-- Show list of users -->
      <div *ngFor = "let item of data?.slice()?.reverse()">
        <!-- When the message type is text the current user sees this-->
        <div class="received chat-box" *ngIf="item.uid == user.uid">
          <h6>{{item.message}}</h6>
          <p>{{item.time.toDate() | date: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a"}}</p>
        </div>
        <!-- When the message type is text friend sees this-->
        <div class="send chat-box" *ngIf="item.uid != user.uid">
          <h6>{{item.message}}</h6>
          <p>{{item.time.toDate() | date: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a"}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="foo">
        <!-- Message text area with attachment -->
          <div class="input-wrap">

            <ion-textarea autosize
                      placeholder="Type Message here"
                      [(ngModel)]="newmessage"
                      (focusin)="onFocus()"
                      >
            </ion-textarea>
            <ion-button fill="clear" slot="end" color="dark" (click)="addmessage()" [disabled]="!newmessage">
              <ion-icon src="\assets\icon\send.svg"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Any one please tell any trick to solve it . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your package.json file make sure your cordova plugin keyboard version is "^2.2.0" or greater. You can simply remove it by

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard
```

add by

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard@2.2.0
```

Then it will work fine because i have try the other below version and there is issue on those version.

Working fine in ionic@5.4.6 and cordova@9.0.0